# How to decrypt a connectionString in a web.config using regiis_asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have tried using this command in cmd but it didn't work

```
c:/path.../regiis_asp.net -pi "connectionString" -app "d:/myWebSiteApp"
```

the result of that command was

```
the configuration section "connectionString" was not found
failed
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Have you tried it this way?:

Encrypt:

```
aspnet_regiis.exe -pef "connectionStrings" C:\path\to\application
```

Decrypt:

```
aspnet_regiis.exe -pdf "connectionStrings" C:\path\to\application
```

Comment: These commands should be executed in this path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 and run as an administrator

Comment: Do you know how to decrypt "connectionString" parameter inside <add> tag? Everyone is writign about connectionStrings but I have hashed attribute's value. After I have changed password to DB I cannot use the app anyome and I dont know old password. <add name="connectionName" connectionString="7R2AR3D3AB5DB48245567F5DB733F21A2824543A77BAFA37537DA54D88FF7D672208870B8B5BC36708D2373664CD3372D77CD8CC265D045AB713871A12RB6DA00RAFD8DF28FRBC38R213667B4R5750R656RF10B07C76177RR880A86D1RB3A54C33467C711A727C34" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

If your intention is to decrypt the connectionStrings section in the web.config, you will have to use the below command.

```
aspnet_regiis -pdf "connectionStrings" -app "d:/MyWebsiteApp"
```

Note: in the code provided by you, please note the following

1) the utility command is **aspnet_regiis** instead of **regiis_asp.net**

2) Since your app is referred from the physical path, the container configuration must be **-pdf** instead of **-pi**

3) The section name is **connectionStrings** instead of **connectionString** ( notice the '**s**')

If you are trying to decrypt from the virtual path then the command must be as below

```
aspnet_regiis -pd "connectionStrings" -app "/MyWebsiteApp"
```

Comment: For those of you like myself who almost never use Command Prompt. I had to change my directory.. cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 before running any aspnet_regiis commands.

Comment: How long does this usually take?  Mine is sitting on Decrypting Configuration section... for 3 minutes now.  File isn't that big so was curious.  Also when I tried doing the -pdf version of this and pointed to the physical folder of the website got a The Parameter "PhysicalDirectory" is invalid.

Comment: @clklachu
Do you know how to decrypt "connectionString" parameter inside <add> tag?
Everyone is writign about connectionStrings but I have hashed attribute's value.
After I have changed password to DB I cannot use the app anyome and I dont know old password.
<add name="connectionName" connectionString="7R2AR3D3AB5DB48245567F5DB733F21A2824543A77BAFA37537DA54D88FF7D672208870B8B5BC36708D2373664CD3372D77CD8CC265D045AB713871A12RB6DA00RAFD8DF28FRBC38R213667B4R5750R656RF10B07C76177RR880A86D1RB3A54C33467C711A727C34" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just had this and it turned out that it didn't want the double quotes around connectionStrings.

Comment: lost way too much time with this silly mistake, just removed the quotes from both the section name and path, like this: aspnet_regiis -pdf connectionStrings C:\path\to\myApp